# Get percentage clicked of elements width along the x-axis

Tags: javascript, html, width, mouseevent, percentage

I have a page structure that looks like in the image below. When clicking anywhere in the `#progress` element I want to calculate how many percentages of it's full width that was clicked.

How can this be done?

```
< div id="progress" onMouseUp={ e => this._seekTo(e) }></div>
```

...

```
_seekTo(event) {
    var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
    console.log((event.clientX - progress.offsetLeft) / progress.offsetWidth * 100)
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Yes, the #progress width is around ~500px and the output numbers are between ~150 and  ~300. I have no padding enabled on the element

Comment: @RolandStarke Thank you for the explanation. It makes perfect sence now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the percentage click position of an elements width along the x-axis like:

```js
document.getElementById('progress').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var bcr = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log('You clicked to ', (e.clientX - bcr.left) / bcr.width);
});
```

> `e.clientX` provides the horizontal coordinate within the application's client area at which the event occurred. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)

Example progress bar:

```js
function mouseSliderPosition(element, e) {
    var bcr = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: Math.min(Math.max(0, (e.clientX - bcr.left) / bcr.width), 1),
        y: Math.min(Math.max(0, (e.clientY - bcr.top) / bcr.height), 1)
    }
};

function activateSlider(e) {
    if (e.touches && e.touches.length > 1) {
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();

    window.activeSlider = this;
    handleSliderMove(e);
}


function handleSliderMove(e) {
    if (e.touches && e.touches.length > 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (window.activeSlider) {
        var progressBar = window.activeSlider.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0];
        var progressFill = window.activeSlider.getElementsByClassName('progress-fill')[0];
        var value = mouseSliderPosition(progressBar, e.touches && e.touches[0] || e).x;
        progressFill.style.transform = 'scaleX(' + value + ')';
    }
}

function deactivateSlider(e) {
    if (e.touches && e.touches.length > 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.activeSlider = null;
}


document.querySelector('.progress-slider').addEventListener('mousedown', activateSlider)
document.querySelector('.progress-slider').addEventListener('touchstart', activateSlider)
window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleSliderMove);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', deactivateSlider);
window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleSliderMove);
window.addEventListener('touchend', deactivateSlider);
window.activeSlider = null;
```

```css
.progress-slider {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.progress-bar {
    height: 2px;
    background: rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
}

.progress-slider:hover .progress-bar {
    height: 3px;
}

.progress-fill {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-slider">
  <div class="progress-bar"><div class="progress-fill"></div></div>
</div>
```